# Minimal working code to add references from .bib file

Tags: bibtex

Can anyone give me the minimal working code to add the references from a `.bib` file to a LaTeX article? I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.
Content of a minimal `.bib` file I made called `references.bib`:

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/

%% Created for Jef Pauwels at 2015-10-05 14:24:21 +0200 

%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 

@book{Giancoli,
    Author = {Douglas C. Giancoli},
    Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
    Publisher = {Pearson},
    Title = {Physics for Scientists & Engineers},
    Year = {2014}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you didn't mention if you use `biblatex` and `biber` or not.  The following MWE works with both.

In your bib file you have one error: you should mask `&` in the title with an `\`!  `\&` prints the letter & in your document.

Compiling MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Giancoli,
  Author    = {Douglas C. Giancoli},
  Publisher = {Pearson},
  Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
  Year      = {2014},
  Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Some \cite{Giancoli} text \autocite{Giancoli}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Package `filecontents`is used to have code and bib file in one MWE.  `\jobname` is replaced with the name of file for the MWE, for example `mwe`if the file is named `mwe.tex`.